# ArgumentError: Write key must be initialized Rails

Tags: rake, nitrousio, dbmigrate

Hi I'm new to Rails and I'm using nitrous.io as my IDE.

I just generated a model using rails `generate model Micropost content:text user:references`

When I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following error: ArgumentError: Write key must be initialized.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Are you using [Segment](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ruby)'s ruby gem by any chance?
It happened to me too and it turned out it was a Segment misconfiguration. The API key was missing.

See the docs:
https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ruby#usage

And this is where the error is fired:
https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ruby/blob/master/lib/segment/analytics/client.rb#L336

Comment: Yes, I was. Thanks for the feedback.