# rake aborted when i do rake db:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

when i do rake db:setup the rake it's aborted and i don't know why...................... because postgresql is running this is the output of postgreql

fabian@Inna-marley:~$ sudo su - postgres
[sudo] contraseña para fabian:
postgres@Inna-marley:~$ psql
psql (13.0 (Ubuntu 13.0-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Digite «help» para obtener ayuda.

postgres=#

this is the output on my terminar

```
rake db:setup
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Write key must be initialized
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/analytics-ruby-2.0.13/lib/segment/analytics/client.rb:319:in `check_write_key!'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/analytics-ruby-2.0.13/lib/segment/analytics/client.rb:28:in `initialize'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/analytics-ruby-2.0.13/lib/segment/analytics.rb:14:in `new'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/analytics-ruby-2.0.13/lib/segment/analytics.rb:14:in `initialize'
/home/fabian/rails-backend/config/initializers/analytics_ruby.rb:3:in `new'
/home/fabian/rails-backend/config/initializers/analytics_ruby.rb:3:in `<main>'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/home/fabian/rails-backend/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/bugsnag-6.18.0/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/fabian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Looking at your gem set, you are stepping upon segment's gem which according to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540448/4472673), you have to apply an API key first.

Comment: and that API key .... where is???

Comment: @fabian you will need to sign up for Segment.io and get an API key through them so it can be used in your app

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to start with checking ENV variables, first of all in `database.yml`.